# Laravel return a value if it is not unique

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I am checking if the value is unique or not in the database using **validation** and here is the code:

```
 public function store(Request $request)
        {
            $select = 'select';

            //logged in user id
            $userid         = Auth::user() -> id;
            $usercountry    = Auth::user() -> country;

            $this -> validate($request, array(
                'number'        => 'required | unique:leads',
                'website'       => 'required | unique:leads',
                'lead_source'   => 'required | not_in:' . $select,
                'industry'      => 'required | not_in:' . $select,
                'action'        => 'required | not_in:' . $select
            ));
}
```

This works perfect but it show me a message telling me if the **website** input is duplicated or not.

What I am trying to do is to return a value from the table **leads** which contain the **website** column.

> I found this code:

```
if ($validator->fails()) {
            $failedRules = $validator->failed();

        }
```

How I could modify it to return a value from the same duplicated row in the **leads** table?

Comment: Why not write your own validation rule that does this?

Comment: Am I need to write a query that return a value from the table when it is duplicated or is there a better way?

Comment: Yeah, just return the value as the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe, something like this work for you

```
            $rules = [
                'number'        => 'required | unique:leads',
                'website'       => 'required | unique:leads',
                'lead_source'   => 'required | not_in:' . $select,
                'industry'      => 'required | not_in:' . $select,
                'action'        => 'required | not_in:' . $select
            ];

            $data = [
                'number.required' => 'number is required.',
                'number.unique' => 'number has already been taken',
                ....
            ];

            $validate = Validator::make($request->all(),$rules,$data);

            if($validate->fails())
            {
                return redirect()->back()->withErrors($validate->errors())->withInput();
            }
```

Comment: yea but how I return a value from a column.. Do i need to write a query for it? I mean is it efficient  or there is a better way?

Comment: Yes, i guess you have to write a query and the result pass to a $data[] with the specific message.

Comment: @Frank Everything is efficient unless you have 100k users and by then you will have team of people coding your app that know what is going on. And yes you need to make an extra query (select) for it.